# What is the expected number of steps that a random walker needs to reach a place with high probability in a 2D lattice?

Tags: probability, random-walk, expected-value, ergodic-theory

Let $L_{m,m}$ be a $2D$ lattice. Also, suppose that there is a random walker located in position $(0,0)$. The random walker goes right, left, up, or down randomly in each step and cannot get out of $L_{m,m}$.

> What is the expected number of steps that the random walker needs to reach $(m,m)$ with high probability?

Comment: What does the walker do when she hits the boundary?  Stay there? Bounce off?

Comment: @kimchilover Bounce off

Comment: So edit your question to include this detail.